# Memcache sessions are lost after page refresh

Tags: php, session, memcached

So I've just moved over to `Memcache` to handle my PHP sessions, and after setting it up from before using `files` for the save handler, I noticed that the session data can be set (`as I've tested inserting data`) but after a page refresh the data is lost.

Code I used to test this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'asd!';
echo "<pre>",print_r($_SESSION),"</pre>";
```

This opt'd the array containing the session data I had just added, after removing the line that adds information to the session array, I refreshed the page and there was no data in the array.

This is the current setup in my `php.ini` to do with `Memcache`:

```
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path    = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:11211?persistant=1'
```

I guessed there was an issue with the `GET` data given to the `save_path`, but I couldn't find any information on the meanings of the requests.

The page that I am trying to load and doing the session adding / loading is `http://localhost/api/get/sessionid` - Which just uses some slugs to load the php script.

Thanks!

**PS:** I'm using TS PHP (`Thread Safe`) (Not sure if that's important, just thought of it)